# list google drive detailed revisions

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to find a way to retrieve a list of Google doc revisions using Google Drive API. I have used the oauthplayground and I get 2 results when listing the revisions of a document. However if I go to Google Drive UI, open this file and check the revisions through "File-see revision history", it will return the same list 2 revisions as I got from the Drive API, but if I click on "Show more detailed revisions" it  returns a larger list of revisions.

Does anyone know how to get this detailed list through Drive API? Or is there any other alternative to get this detailed list of revisions?

Comment: Hi, pretty much I've just tried to use the operator https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}/revisions to get the list of revisions, not sure what else should I use in the API to get the revisions.

Comment: This is the first instance of this question: [13107369](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107369/how-to-get-a-detailed-list-of-google-doc-revisions-in-drive-api)