# Google REST API v3 - Revisions:list vs "Show more detailed revisions"

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I need to get the detailed list of the revisions for a Google Document.
When using the Google API Explorer on:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/revisions
```

I get only the non-detailed list.

Which is the API to call (or the parameter to set) in order to get something similar to what can be seen by pressing **Show more detailed revisions**?

**Update:**
I tried to "sniff" the browser traffic and I realized that Google Drive periodically requests the revision list to the URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{fileId}/revisions/history?id={fileId}&start=1&end=-1&zoom_level=0&token={token}
```

When clicking on *Show more detailed revisions*, the previous URL becomes:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{fileId}/revisions/history?id={fileId}&start=1&end=-1&zoom_level=1&token={token}
```

(the *zoom_level* parameter changes from *0* to *1*)
I cannot find anything like that on the API reference, though. It seems that such an URL has to be invoked manually.
Therefore, I manually generated a token for the *drive* scope, manually checked it in order to keep it fresh and manually invoked that URL, in order to see what happened. Unfortunately, I got the following error on the browser:

```
Impossibile aprire il file in questo momento.
Verifica l'indirizzo e riprova.
```

which roughly means:

```
Unable to open the file at the moment.
Please verify the address and try again.
```

May somebody point me towards the right direction?

Comment: I just requested this as an optional feature on the public documented drive.revisions.list Google Drive API. If you're looking for this functionality as well, please 'Star' the request by clicking the star next to the issue number here:  https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5001

Comment: @TimothyJohns Thanks for the issue, starred. Were you able to manually fiddle with the zoom_level parameter to get it to work that way?

Comment: @Harry I tried passing in zoom_level as a param to drive.revisions.list, but got the same results as without it. As far as the /revisions route on the doc URL itself (vs API) honestly I didn't try that approach. The OP indicated the token he used there didn't work, and I don't believe the sub-routes on those Docs URLS is documented. Those two things when combined were enough to discourage me from trying it, but if someone else did get that to work well, I'd also consider doing so as an interim solution. My opinion is that it really fits cleanly in the API, really hope it makes it there.

Answer (score 0):

In the "[Try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list#try-it)" section of the API there is a field called "fields". In there you can select the files you need from the response. If you write "kind,revisions"  you will get the complete information or you can use the "fields editor" to select the fields you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But please let me clarify that the problem it's not about the fields of a single revision; on the contrary, the problem concerns the number of revisions I get. That API seems to return only the "main revisions", that is the same list you get when you open a google document and click on "Revision history". Instead, I want to get the complete list, i.e. the list that you get when you click on "Show more detailed revisions".